# Invalid list operation: index 0, size 0

Tags: java, android

Here's my **code when edit text changed** (the problem appeared after i wanted to make a search for listview(*publicapps*) using edittext)

**What should i do to fix the error**... The problem appears when i type something that is not equals the `_charSeq`

As i got it **gives an error when the map** (pubmap) deletes the position

````
if (stris.equals("p")) {
    if (Searchby.equals("1")) {
        progressbar6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pub.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot _dataSnapshot) {
                pubmap = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                    for (DataSnapshot _data : _dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> _map = _data.getValue(_ind);
                        pubmap.add(_map);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception _e) {
                    _e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (_charSeq.length() > 0) {
                    n3 = pubmap.size() - 1;
                    n4 = pubmap.size();
                    for(int _repeat84 = 0; _repeat84 < (int)(n4); _repeat84++) {
                        if (pubmap.get((int)n3).get("pubflair").toString().toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {
                            
                        }
                        else {
                            pubmap.remove((int)(n3));
                        }
                        n3--;
                    }
                }
                publicapps.setAdapter(new PublicappsAdapter(pubmap));
                progressbar6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError _databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        progressbar6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pub.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot _dataSnapshot) {
                pubmap = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                    for (DataSnapshot _data : _dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> _map = _data.getValue(_ind);
                        pubmap.add(_map);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception _e) {
                    _e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (_charSeq.length() > 0) {
                    n3 = pubmap.size() - 1;
                    n4 = pubmap.size();
                    for(int _repeat146 = 0; _repeat146 < (int)(n4); _repeat146++) {
                        if (pubmap.get((int)n3).get("pubname").toString().toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {
                            
                        }
                        else {
                            pubmap.remove((int)(n3));
                        }
                        n3--;
                    }
                }
                publicapps.setAdapter(new PublicappsAdapter(pubmap));
                progressbar6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError _databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Thats a whole bunch of code, please show your full error stacktrace along with a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, i did as u said, did it as short as possible

Comment: This is a difficult question to examine, with no comments in your code and not much else to go on.  But I will suggest that perhaps instead of adding everything and then removing the unwanted items, that you rather just build up pubmap from the source list with just the items you want to keep.

Comment: A [mre] doesn't mean the question should as short as possible, just that the code should be, providing it is possible to compile and run it, and that anybody else can do so.

Comment: *"it gives an error when the map (pubmap) deletes the position"* That's **impossible**, because if `pubmap.remove((int)(n3));` *(the "delete position" operation)* would throw that exception, the preceding `pubmap.get((int)n3).get("pubflair")` would have thrown a `NullPointerException`, and the code would never reach the `remove()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I recommended to you divide your code into small functionality cause when u have a problem is easier found an error.

apparently *bupmap* is empty or not exist an index ( pass by params " int)(n3) ")..please can u write the stack error here?

regards!!